# Assertion failure while trying to pop views from the navigation stack

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, assertions

I'm trying to pop to a specific view controller that is in the navigation stack but I am doing something wrong as I am getting this error pop up when I try to execute the code

```
Assertion failure in -[UINavigationController popToViewController:transition:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UINavigationController.m:2229
```

Here is the code thats causing the issue

```
FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController.xib" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController popToViewController:firstViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Is there anything between the two lines of code from your example?

Comment: nope thats exactly what they are, inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to find an example else where which works perfectly.

//Just choose objectAtIndex number to pop to a particulart point on the navigation stack

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pop an instance of a controller that you have not pushed yet, even though it may be  identical to another controller to which you would like to return.

In your code snippet, you are trying to pop the stack of the navigation controller to a newly created object. This controller is not on the stack, because you have just created it. Since the navigation controller cannot find a controller that you are looking for, it throws an error.

Comment: Alright, well the firstViewController is on there I have just declared it in this view because it was not appearing when I was typing popToViewController... I dunno what I am supposed to do.

Comment: @C.Johns Define a variable to store a pointer to the `firstViewController` object that you created in your initialization code before pushing it onto the stack. Use the value of that variable in the code that pops the stack to your first view controller.