# Can't transition to Level 2 (using UINavigationController)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

In my `GameViewController` class, I have this method `displayWinScreen` which gets the current level number and stores it in a public property in my `WinViewController` class called `levelCompleted`.  It then runs this method called `runPushAnimationWithController:` which just pushes the `WinViewController` object onto the UINavigation stack.

```
    - (void)displayWinScreen {
        WinViewController *winViewController = [[WinViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WinViewController"
                                                             bundle:nil];
        winViewController.levelCompleted = self.levelNumber;
        [self runPushAnimationWithController:winViewController];
    }
```

Then in `WinViewController` I set a button that, when pressed on the iPhone, calls this method:

```
    -(IBAction)nextLevelSelection:(id)sender {
        int num = [self.levelCompleted integerValue];
        int newNum = num + 2;
        self.levelCompleted = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:newNum];
        GameViewController* nextLevelViewController = [[GameViewController alloc]
                                                 initWithNibName:@"GameViewController"
                                               bundle:nil];
        nextLevelViewController.levelNumber = self.levelCompleted;
        [self runPushAnimationWithController:nextLevelViewController];
```

}

This method just increases that property value, and stores it in the `GameViewController` property `levelNumber`.  When I put a breakpoint to see if that int number gets passed, everything checks out.  If I originally played level 3, the number that eventually is `nextLevelViewController.levelNumber` is 4.  Ignore the `num + 2`, the way I have it set up, the int value still will the increase the level by 1.

I use this same process of passing int properties for all my other UINavigationController methods and everything is ok.  Except for this.  Should I popping the controller or use another technique for view controller transitioning?

Here's the pop method I use to go back to the `GameViewController` from `WinViewController`.

```
    -(void)runPopperAnimation:(UIViewController*)viewController {
        CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
        transition.duration = 0.30f;
        transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
        transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
        [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:viewController animated:NO];
    }
```

Comment: so what's the problem??

Comment: Right.....sorry.  I get an Assertion Failure when trying to push onto the stack for the next level (and same thing with popping to the previous controller).  I read somewhere that I need a reference to the view controller I already created instead of alloc-init a new one.

Comment: What does the assertion failure say? The whole point of an assertion failure is to tell you what went wrong.

Comment: Assertion failure in -[UINavigationController popToViewController:transition:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UINavigationController.m:2642

Comment: So any thoughts or what?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code  - where popToViewController is called? The code you have posted doesn't show this.

Comment: I suspect the issue is similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829905/assertion-failure-while-trying-to-pop-views-from-the-navigation-stack Look at the code which calls your runPopperAnimation method, and see if the viewController you are passing in is actually on the View Stack.

Comment: And I am really intent on using that solution, however, how would I be able to pass that `levelCompleted` property from the `WinViewController` back up to the `GameViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

> how would I be able to pass that levelCompleted property from the
>   WinViewController back up to the GameViewController?

One way is to store it to a separate singleton class:

DataModel.h

```
@interface DataModel : NSObject

@property NSInteger *levelCompleted;

+ (id)sharedModel;
```

DataModel.m

```
#import "DataModel.h"

@implementation DataModel

@synthesize levelCompleted;

/* Return singleton model */
+ (id)sharedModel {
    static DataModel *sharedModel = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedModel = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedModel;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
         self.levelCompleted = 0;

    return self;
}
```

You can then call this class from anywhere in your code and modify it's properties:

```
NSInteger levelCompleted = [DataModel sharedModel].levelCompleted;
```

To increment the value:

```
[DataModel sharedModel].levelCompleted+=1;
```

With this method, the levelCompleted will only persist over the lifecycle of the app execution. If you restart the device or close the app, the value is lost.

*BUT*

If you want to persist across restarts then you can save it to NSUserDefaults instead. This will persist of the lifetime of the app install:

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

To Retrieve the value:

```
NSNumber *levelCompleted =[standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"levelCompleted"];
```

To Save the value:

```
[stadardUserDefaults setObject:levelCompleted forKey:@"levelCompleted"];
```

Comment: Wow...brilliant, thanks for all your help.  Didn't even know you could do any of that.

Comment: Just out curiosity, I am unable to use `[DateModel sharedModel].levelCompleted`.  I receive the error 'property levelCompleted not found on object of type 'id''.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You have typed in the comment 'DateModel' instead of 'DataModel' - could that be it? If not then post your code.